# Administer Payment Processor Page Error

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, stripe

I am installing a new installation of Civicrm 5.58.0 on Wordpress 6.1.1.  I am trying to add Stripe as a payment processor on the "Administer Payment Processor" page and the only processor I can add is Paypal - Website Payment Pro.  I have the Stripe extension installed along with the associated other extensions required.  However, when I chose "Stripe" as the processor when adding a new processor, the screen immediately refreshes and redirects back to the "Administer Payment Processor" page without adding Stripe...  I am not even able to enter any Stripe specifics because as soon as I select Stripe in the dropdown, the page redirects.  This happens on all the other processors as well.  As a test, I installed Authorize.net's extension and tried to add that one as a processor with the same redirect occurring as soon as selected it in the dropdown.

I get no error in the console or Civicrm log files, apache logs or syslog.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the experimental 'CiviCRM Administration UI' extension?  There was a problem like this in 5.58 that is fixed for 5.59.  Try disabling that extension, or applying https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25340